# Hopital rule does it fail in this particular example?

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\dfrac{n}{1}}$$

Using L'hopital's rule
$$\dfrac{d}{dn}n=1 , \dfrac{d}{dn} 1=0$$

So:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\dfrac{n}{1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\dfrac{1}{0}}=\infty$$
is this correct?

Comment: The hypotheses for the rule are not satisifed for ${n\over 1}$.

Comment: Why David Mitra?

Comment: because infinity over one is not indeterminate

Comment: But 
     lim  1/x = oo
     n→0

Comment: and what does that have to do with the question?

Comment: by the way, in the future please use latex for math formatting.

Comment: OpenBSD is so slow when using latex

Comment: Okay, l'Hôpital's rule requires **first** that you check that the numerator and denominator both have the same limit, and that the limit is either zero or infinite. this is not the case for your example, so you can't use l'Hôpital's rule. The limit of 1 is 1

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule

Comment: @Integralsandseries please read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule   and before asking your questions check if your question is a valid question in terms of the definition of what you are asking!

Comment: You can't just apply the rule willy nilly. There are conditions that have to be met in order for it to be valid. Those conditions are not met, so it is not valid to use the rule.

Comment: What are those conditions?

Comment: I have said it already. The numerator and the denominator have to have the same limit, and that limit has to be 0 or infinity. also both have to be differentiable.

Comment: LHR cannot apply into this indeterminate form

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[l'Hospital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) is not applicable here because your limit is of the form
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
Where $f(x) = x, g(x) = 1$ and thus
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty} x = \infty, \quad \lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty} 1 = 1$$
l'Hospital requires the two limits to be equal and to be either $0$ or $\pm\infty$.

---

**Remark**: The rule applies in a slightly more general condition:

> If $\left|\lim\limits_{x\to c} g(x)\right|=\infty$, the limit of $f$ is irrelevant.

This works because if $f$ is bounded (For example $\left|\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x)\right| <\infty$), the limit will always be $0$ and if it is not, we are in the form $\frac{\pm\infty}{\pm\infty}$ from the original rule.

Comment: @DavidMitra Included the remark and a little elaboration how to prove it starting at the stronger requirement.

Comment: The "extended rule" also applies if $\lim f$ doesn't exist (which makes the version non-trivial).

Comment: @DavidMitra couldn't you substitute $\lim\sup$ and $\lim\inf$ in that case?